# Creating subfolders inside iPad folders

Tags: ipad

I would like to know is it possible to add subfolders inside my ipad folder without jail breaking my device

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has API's like ["`createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a) which you can use on folders where you have permission to write new files & folders into (such as the "Documents" or "Cache" directory).

Make certain to look at the "`BOOL`" return value from API's and if they return "`FALSE`", check the "`NSError`" parameter at the end of that API which will give you great hints as to what might have gone wrong with the way you were calling it.